# PDF Output with Knitr for Latex Equations

Tags: pdf, latex, knitr, r-markdown

I am having trouble getting multi-line latex equations to successfully compile when using knitr in R Markdown. When I output as an HTML file it works but when I attempt to output as a PDF I get errors and it will not compile.

The following sample code illustrates the problem. Just change `output:html_document` to `output: pdf_document`. You'll see that in HTML output both Test 1 and Test 2 work. But in PDF output only Test 1 successfully compiles.

```
---
title: "Test"
date: "1/16/2018"
output: html_document
---

## R Markdown   
Testing to see if a multi-line latex equation works.

#### Test 1:
$$ f(x) = x^5 + x^3 + x $$
$$ g(x) = y^{x+1} $$

#### Test 2:  
\begin{align}
f(x) &= x^5 + x^3 + x \\
g(x) &= y^{x+1}
\end{align}
```

I am running Mac OS X - High Sierra and R Studio - Version 1.1.383

The following is the error I got:

```
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Non-existent destination files:
      'Untitled.pdf'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -recorder  "Untitled.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'Untitled.log' for details
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs of latex/pdflatex.
! Paragraph ended before \align was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.112 

Error: Failed to compile Untitled.tex. See Untitled.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce this. My specs: `MacOS 10.13.2, RStudio 1.1.408, R 3.4.3, knitr 1.18, rmarkdown 1.8, pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017)`

Comment: When things fail, [please clearly show the failure](https://yihui.name/en/2017/09/the-minimal-reprex-paradox/). Don't just say "it doesn't work" or "I get errors". What exactly are the errors?

Comment: Apologies... I included the error info at the bottom.